# Multiple Highcharts in one page - only one chart displays

Tags: javascript, flask, highcharts

I'm in the process of creating a Flask application, for the charting element I want to use Highcharts, I've managed to get one chart to display on a webpage but as soon as I try to display multiple charts only one renders.

I have tried a number of things to start, changing variable names, checked line by line code to see if there is an issue with one chart. Commented out one chart then the other to make sure they both work. Finally I have inspected the script in Chrome to see what is returned, everything looks fine.

I believe the issue is in my variable declaration in my script element. If I leave it as chart_id for both I think the first chart is being overwritten, however if I change the var to chart_id1 and chart_id2, neither chart returns?

I have tried to label all the variables under "div id={{ chart1ID|safe }}" as chart1_id, series1 etc ....and all the variables under "id={{ chart2ID|safe }}" as 2. When I inspect the code in Chrome everything looks to be returning correctly but no chart renders.

```
.../static/main.js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(chart1_id).highcharts({
    chart1: chart1,
    title1: title1,
    xAxis1: xAxis1,
    yAxis1: yAxis1,
    series1: series1
})
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(chart2_id).highcharts({
    chart2: chart2,
    title2: title2,
    xAxis2: xAxis2,
    yAxis2: yAxis2,
    series2: series2
})});
```

HTML

```
..../templates/index.html
    <body>

<div id={{ chart1ID|safe }} class="chart1" style="height: 500px; width: 500px">
    <script>
        var chart_id = {{ chart1ID|safe }}
        var series = {{ series1|safe }}
        var title = {{ title1|safe }}
        var xAxis = {{ xAxis1|safe }}
        var yAxis = {{ yAxis1|safe }}
        var chart = {{ chart1|safe }}
    </script>
    </div>

    <br>
    <P>***********************************************************************************</P>

    <div id={{ chart2ID|safe }} class="chart2" style="height: 500px; width: 500px">
    <script>
        var chart_id = {{ chart2ID|safe }}
        var series = {{ series2|safe }}
        var title = {{ title2|safe }}
        var xAxis = {{ xAxis2|safe }}
        var yAxis = {{ yAxis2|safe }}
        var chart = {{ chart2|safe }}
    </script>
    </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index(chart1ID = 'chart1_ID', chart1_type = 'line', chart1_height = 500, chart2ID = 'chart2_ID', chart2_type = 'line', chart2_height = 500):
  chart1 = {"renderTo": chart1ID, "type": chart1_type, "height": chart1_height,}
  series1 = [{"name": 'Label1', "data": [1,2,3]}, {"name": 'Label2', "data": [9, 10, 11]}]
  title1 = {"text": 'Chart 1 Title'}
  xAxis1 = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
  yAxis1 = {"title": {"text": 'yAxis Label'}}

  chart2 = {"renderTo": chart2ID, "type": chart2_type, "height": chart2_height,}
  series2 = [{"name": 'Label1', "data": [1,2,3]}, {"name": 'Label2', "data": [14, 15, 20]}]
  title2 = {"text": 'Second Chart Title'}
  xAxis2 = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
  yAxis2 = {"title": {"text": 'yAxis Label'}}
  return render_template('index.html',
                         chart1ID=chart1ID, chart1=chart1, series1=series1, title1=title1, xAxis1=xAxis1, yAxis1=yAxis1,
                         chart2ID=chart2ID, chart2=chart2, series2=series2, title2=title2, xAxis2=xAxis2, yAxis2=yAxis2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I can't see the wood for the trees with this at the moment, I imagine it is something basic I am overlooking. This is all the code I am working with at the moment, I removed it from a larger application to make it clearer when posting the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

All you need is to change your var's at HTML document to var series1, title1 etc.
My working code:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% block head %}
        <title>{% block title %}Title!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    <div id={{ chart1ID|safe }} class="chart1" style="height: 500px; width: 1000px"></div>
    <script>
        var chart1_id = {{ chart1ID|safe }}
        var series1 = {{ series1|safe }}
        var title1 = {{ title1|safe }}
        var xAxis1 = {{ xAxis1|safe }}
        var yAxis1 = {{ yAxis1|safe }}
        var chart1 = {{ chart1|safe }}
    </script>

    <div id={{ chart2ID|safe }} class="chart2" style="height: 500px; width: 1000px">
 <script>
         var chart2_id = {{ chart2ID|safe }}
         var series2 = {{ series2|safe }}
         var title2 = {{ title2|safe }}
         var xAxis2 = {{ xAxis2|safe }}
         var yAxis2 = {{ yAxis2|safe }}
         var chart2 = {{ chart2|safe }}
 </script>
 </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="../static/js/graph.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(chart1_id).highcharts({
    chart: chart1,
    title: title1,
    xAxis: xAxis1,
    yAxis: yAxis1,
    series: series1
 });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(chart2_id).highcharts({
  chart: chart2,
  title: title2,
  xAxis: xAxis2,
  yAxis: yAxis2,
  series: series2
})});
```

And Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index(chart1ID = 'chart1_ID', chart1_type = 'line', chart1_height = 500, 
chart2ID = 'chart2_ID', chart2_type = 'line', chart2_height = 500):
  chart1 = {"renderTo": chart1ID, "type": chart1_type, "height": chart1_height,}
  series1 = [{"name": 'Label1', "data": [1,2,3]}, {"name": 'Label2', "data": [9, 10, 11]}]
  title1 = {"text": 'Chart 1 Title'}
  xAxis1 = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
  yAxis1 = {"title": {"text": 'yAxis Label'}}


  chart2 = {"renderTo": chart2ID, "type": chart2_type, "height": chart2_height,}
  series2 = [{"name": 'Label1', "data": [1,2,3]}, {"name": 'Label2', "data": [14, 15, 20]}]
  title2 = {"text": 'Second Chart Title'}
  xAxis2 = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
  yAxis2 = {"title": {"text": 'yAxis Label'}}
  return render_template('index.html', chart1ID=chart1ID, chart1=chart1, series1=series1, title1=title1, xAxis1=xAxis1, yAxis1=yAxis1, chart2ID=chart2ID, chart2=chart2, series2=series2, title2=title2, xAxis2=xAxis2, yAxis2=yAxis2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug = True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, passthrough_errors=True)
```

When you will try to copy this Python code remember to format equals spaces before variables(for example one tab before every variable - [tab]chart1 = {...} [tab]series1 = {...} etc).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've just run this and it returns a blank page. The script in the html page picks up the values, I can see them when I inspect, however, in the console element it now states "Uncaught ReferenceError: chart_id is not defined"

Comment: If I change var chart1_id to var chart_id and so on for that section and re-run, this chart renders. 
       var chart_id = {{ chart1ID|safe }}
        var series = {{ series1|safe }}
        var title = {{ title1|safe }}
        var xAxis = {{ xAxis1|safe }}
        var yAxis = {{ yAxis1|safe }}
        var chart = {{ chart1|safe }}
..but I can't do this for both charts, I can't see at the moment how to display multiple as the only var name that works is chart_id???

Answer (score 1):

In your first code block, you provide chart options to highcharts as `chart1, title1` etc. Highcharts expect those options to be `chart, title` and this structure has to be the same in both charts (API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/):

```
.../static/main.js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(chart1_id).highcharts({
    chart: chart1,
    title: title1,
    xAxis: xAxis1,
    yAxis: yAxis1,
    series: series1
})
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(chart2_id).highcharts({
    chart: chart2,
    title: title2,
    xAxis: xAxis2,
    yAxis: yAxis2,
    series: series2
})});
```

In the HTML code, you've created global js variables which have the same names in both places that's why options for the second chart will overwrite the first ones. Perhaps a better idea is to create two global objects with chart options (chartOptions1 and chartOptions2) and then use these objects to initialize charts or just use python variables to initialize the chart in the highcharts chart object right away:

**HTML:**

```
..../templates/index.html
<body>

    <div id={{ chart1ID|safe }} class="chart1" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>

    <br>
    <P>***********************************************************************************</P>

    <div id={{ chart2ID|safe }} class="chart2" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var chart1_id = {{ chart1ID|safe }};
        var chart2_id = {{ chart2ID|safe }};

        $('#' + chart1_id).highcharts({
            chart: {{ chart1|safe }},
            title: {{ title1|safe }},
            xAxis: {{ xAxis1|safe }},
            yAxis: {{ yAxis1|safe }},
            series: {{ series1|safe }}
        });

        $('#' + chart2_id).highcharts({
            chart: {{ chart2|safe }},
            title: {{ title2|safe }},
            xAxis: {{ xAxis2|safe }},
            yAxis: {{ yAxis2|safe }},
            series: {{ series2|safe }}
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Wojciech but that doesn't work/I still have something wrong. There are no errors, but the charts will not display, just a blank page?

Comment: The solution above gives the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: chart_id is not defined.

Comment: I can't find `chart_id` in the code I send you above. Perhaps you've changed the variables names here and left old name `chart_id` somewhere. The error should point you exactly where is the issue. Please correct it and check again.

Comment: It doesn’t recognise chart1_id, it asks for a chart_id. This is mentioned no where in the code.

Comment: In the other example provided I get the same response. I change chart1_id to chart_id a chart renders. I change that var name to anything else, error.

Comment: Remember that my answer is only a tip. Unfortunately, I have no idea how your whole app looks and why this error occurs.

Comment: Understood, at the moment the above is everything as I’ve stripped everything out. Can’t get my head around why as soon as I change a variable name (chart_id to chart1_id) highcharts won’t recognise. If I don’t change I can only ever return one chart.

Comment: This error is not caused by Highcharts, but JS itself. You're simply using a variable that has never been declared. Unfortunately, I'm not able to tell you where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

*** UPDATE ***
So I couldn't understand why this wasn't working. Seemed too simple to not work, with two good answers provided above.

I deleted the project I was working on, (built in PyCharm), and then rebuilt the project and relaunched. Using Sebastian example above I was able to display both charts without an issue. I don't know whether there was a caching issue, there was a trailing space somewhere or the project had become corrupted. Update provided for anyone else that comes across this issue.